# Safari: 1 pixel shift in iframe content on :hover animation

Tags: iframe, layout, safari, css-transforms

Safari-specific:

I have got a page which is simply a background with an iframe centered in it. The iframe uses transform animations on :hover, and these cause the iframe content to make a little unwanted 1-pixel shift to the left **only in Safari** (tested in Chrome & Firefox).

I'm not sure what might be causing Safari to do this.

- My iframe is width: 100%, so presumably the frame itself isn't
  shifting, only the content.
- The shift only lasts for the duration of the animation, not the hover.
- The shift *doesn't* occur on the page that is the source of the iframe content, only once it is displayedcwithin the iframe.

Has anyone encountered this issue in Safari?

Page with Safari issue: http://www.bladesnpc.com/index-02.html

Content within iframe: https://perchance.org/blades-npc

Answer (score 0):

I am managing the element centering with flex. Changing the `flex-direction` to `column` solved the Safari problem—although this particular fix only works because I am centering a single element on the page.